# Read data frame of factors (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, text-files, r-factor, bayesian-networks

I am a novice to R. To use in a package I need a "data frame of factors".

I have a text file of form:

```
A B C ...
1 3 2
2 2 3
3 1 1
2 2 1
3 1 2
```

So each column represents a variable that can be 1, 2 or 3. 
Please suggest a command that allow me to get a Data Frame of factors from such a text file (just reading the file as a matrix won't do, I am required to have real 'factors').

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that setting the `colClasses` parameter of `read.table` to:

```
colClasses = c(rep("factor",26))
```

would do the job I require.

Comment: Another way, if you want to do after loading is: `df[] <- lapply(df, as.factor)`. Although it's much better to deal with it using `colClasses` during loading.

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- read.table(textConnection("A B C
1 3 2
2 2 3
3 1 1
2 2 1
3 1 2"), header=T, colClasses="factor")

str(a)
## 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 2 3
##  $ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 2 1 2 1
##  $ C: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 3 1 1 2
```